# Convert boolean value to yes/no by angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I need to show Boolean value to yes/no using directive. My directive is given below

```
 directives.directive('niBooltoYesno',
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                    function formatter(value) {
                        if (value) {
                            return value === true ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                        } else {
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                    ngModel.$formatters.push(formatter);

                }
            };
        });

<ni-boolto-yesno data-ng-model="set_unit.isActive" ></ni-boolto-yesno>
```

But it does not work. Please help me in this point.

Comment: You should describe exactly _how_ it doesn't work or provide a jsfiddle/codepen.

Comment: why not something like just {{user.booleanValue?'yes':'no'}}

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're not using the right tool for the job. This should be a filter:

```
{{ someBooleanValue | yesNo }}
```

The filter would be as simple as

```
module.filter('yesNo', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input ? 'yes' : 'no';
    }
});
```

If you still choose to use a directive, you don't need ngModel and formatters, which is used on form fields that must read and write to a model. All you need is a template:

```
module.directive('yesNo', function() {
    return {
        template: '<span>{{ yesNo ? "yes" : "no" }}</span>',
        scope: {
            yesNo: '='
        }
    };
});
```

and you woud use it as

```
<span yes-no="someBoolean"></span>
```

Comment: Filter is perfect for my case.

Answer (score 17):

I define textual values for 0 and 1 with...

```
{{object.PROPERTY?'Yes':'No'}}
```

...when presented with something like this:

```
{
  "PROPERTY": 0
}
```

The result would then be 'No'.

Comment: This is really the better answer. It's simple and clean. The answer by JB Nizet works perfectly fine but is overkill in this scenario. It's suited to more complex occasions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `if (value)`. This causes the `return value === true ? ...` line to be processed only when the value is actually truthy (i.e. never for `false`). You just need to construct the conditions properly:

```
function formatter (value) {
    return (value === true) ? 'Yes' : ((value === false) ? 'No' : '');
}
```

---

A version with better readability:

```
function formatter (value) {
    if (value === true) {
        return 'Yes';
    } else if (value === false) {
        return 'No';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I haven't looked at your HTML. As another answer points out, using `ng-model` for this is a bad idea, creating a filter should suit you just fine.

Comment: the nesting on your if statements is a little off (formatted version). You are not adding an else-if block. The else block of the ternary operator would contain a second if else block

Comment: @Kieran `if A { X } else { if B { Y } else { Z } }` is equivalent to `if A { X } else if B { Y } else { Z }` and flattened code is always easier to read.